# PHP - Repond with an echo - Then run a long PHP script

Tags: php, response, httpresponse, output-buffering

Hi I have an issue where I have XML posted to my PHP file, I then need to echo "Received" and then run through the data.

The client sending the XML has a 30 second time limit to receive a response. As the script takes longer than 30 seconds to run the echo isn't spat out until the end of the script has finished!

I want it to hit my PHP file, echo immediately and then do the script afterwards. I tried Output Buffering, tried every server config / script I can find and just can't get it to work!

Any way I can get around this?

Comment: You could always try to increase the timeout both on the client and the server. If this is not an option then de-couple the logic of receiving the file from the actual processing of the xml. You can do this by storing the xml and processing it later in a background job. The client gets a "received" message, he can later get a "processed" message too.

Comment: Thanks, I can't change the client timeout, I can store the XML in a file no problem but how do I then later process this do you have any tips on what is the best method?

Comment: I wouldn't know about the _best_ method but you can always try to save the files on the disk and the paths in a database along with a user_id, uploaded timestamp, processed timestamp. Then set up a cron job to go through the database table and take the files one by one, process them, and update the table..

Comment: What about saving the XML file on the server and then make an secondary script that manipulates the data. Then make a cronjob that runs the script every minute or something like that.